# Pandas dataframe add 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to be able to add the values of two dataframes with the same structure together and form a new dataframe as a result.

e.g. DF1 + DF2 = DF3

```
DF1
+------------+----+----+----+
|    date    |  A |  B |  C |
+------------+----+----+----+
| 2017-01-01 | 24 | 15 |  4 |
| 2017-01-02 | 31 | 10 | 12 |
| 2017-01-03 |  9 | 47 |  3 |
+------------+----+----+----+

DF2
+------------+----+----+----+
|    date    |  A |  B |  C |
+------------+----+----+----+
| 2017-01-01 |  4 | 12 | 63 |
| 2017-01-02 | 23 |  0 | 31 |
| 2017-01-03 | 61 | 22 | 90 |
+------------+----+----+----+

DF3
+------------+----+----+----+
|    date    |  A |  B |  C |
+------------+----+----+----+
| 2017-01-01 | 28 | 27 | 67 |
| 2017-01-02 | 64 | 10 | 43 |
| 2017-01-03 | 70 | 69 | 93 |
+------------+----+----+----+
```

I've been trying to work out how to do this but i'm getting a TypeError

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.date' and 'datetime.date'
```

when trying to do:

```
df3 = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
```

I'm sure i'm missing something simple as it appears to be trying to add the first columns (which is a date and the column I want to match on to add together the values for all other columns) but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you take out the date column and add it later on, it should work. is this a possiblity given the structure of your data? it will work in the above case.

Comment: The dates need to remain linked to the data otherwise the data isn't any good. I suppose basically what I need is to add up the corresponding columns based on the date matching between the datafrmes

Comment: Another option would be using concat, groupby and sum: `df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('date').sum().reset_index()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the `date` columns to be indices, not normal columns:

```
df3 = df1.set_index('date').add(df2.set_index('date'), fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

You use [`set_index()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) so that the date columns becomes indices.  If you don't want the final dataframe to be date-indexed, you can use [`reset_index()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) at the end as @MaxU suggests.

Comment: i'd also add `.reset_index()` at the end ;-)

Comment: @ASGM, thanks very much for your help. Adding the indices was the solution I needed :)